# Check array of object to find double

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this :

```
array = [
   {x: 205, y: 205}
   {x: 230, y: 205}
   {x: 255, y: 205}
   {x: 205, y: 205}
   {x: 205, y: 205}
   {x: 205, y: 205}
]
```

I want check if my array contain the same object once( for example the 3 last objects are the same) so I want just delete them.

If I select or deselect a item , I just want the coordinates of the selected item in the array

```
    function selectFixture() {
      const item = new PIXI.Graphics();
      // check if place is empty
      if (this.isDown) {
        this.isDown = false;
        console.log(this.isDown)
        item.beginFill(colors[1]);
        item.drawRect(this.positionX, this.positionY, tileH, tileW);
        container.addChild(item);
        console.log(finalArray)
      } else {
        this.isDown = true;
        console.log(this.isDown)
        item.beginFill(colors[2]);
        item.drawRect(this.positionX, this.positionY, tileH, tileW);
        container.addChild(item);
        selectedFixtures.push({
          x: this.positionX,
          y: this.positionY,
        })
        console.log(selectedFixtures)
        var finalArray = {};
        for (var i = 0, len = selectedFixtures.length; i < len; i++)
          finalArray[selectedFixtures[i]['x']] = selectedFixtures[i];
        selectedFixtures = new Array();
        for (var key in finalArray)
          selectedFixtures.push(finalArray[key]);
        console.log(finalArray)
      }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/WNQLxaw

How can I do this ?

Comment: no because it's an array of objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I try it but I don't have good result

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/WNQLxaw

Comment: when I select multiple value on Y , it don't add in the array

Comment: Please put it in the question itself. Links can go down over time and the idea is to curate questions and answers that are useful for future visitors, not just you. See [ask] and take the [tour]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function and a small trick in finding the first index of the current item to remove duplicates like the following:

```js
array = [
   {x: 205, y: 205},
   {x: 230, y: 205},
   {x: 255, y: 205},
   {x: 205, y: 205},
   {x: 205, y: 205},
   {x: 205, y: 205}
]

array = array.filter((item, index) => {
  let ind = array.findIndex(obj => obj.x+"$"+obj.y === item.x+"$"+item.y);
  return ind === index;
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Can you check my codepen and tell me if I remove an element on the map , haw can I remove it from the array

Comment: I think , you answer is close that I like to have , but I can remove an element

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let  array=[  { x: 205, y: 205 },
{ x: 230, y: 205 },
{ x: 255, y: 205 },
{ x: 205, y: 205 },
{ x: 205, y: 205 },
{ x: 205, y: 205 },]

const removeDuplicates =(array)=> {

   let obj = {}
   array.forEach((elem) => {
      obj[elem.x + "-" + elem.y] = 0
   })

   let newArray = []
   console.log(obj)
   array.forEach((elem) => {
      if (obj[elem.x + "-" + elem.y] !== undefined) {
        if (obj[elem.x + "-" + elem.y] == 0) {
            obj[elem.x + "-" + elem.y] = 1
            newArray.push(elem)
        }
    }


    })
    console.log(newArray)

    return newArray 
 }
```

Comment: I update the my code , but it don't remove any value. Can test it with my codepen's code ?

Answer (score 0):

One more way to solve this.

```js
let array = [{x: 205, y: 205},{x: 230, y: 205},{x: 255, y: 205},
{x: 205, y: 205},{x: 205, y: 205},{x: 205, y: 205}]

let sortedArray = []

array.forEach(elem => {
  if (!sortedArray.includes(JSON.stringify(elem))) {
      sortedArray.push(JSON.stringify(elem))
  }
})
sortedArray = sortedArray.map(elem => JSON.parse(elem))
console.log(sortedArray)
```